# Understanding why its $xy$ and not $2xy$ in the solution of a nonexact differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

Here is the problem and its solution:

> [image]
> [image]

My question is:

Why it is $xy$ and not $2xy$ in the general solution of the non-exact differential equation? as there is one term $xy$ resulting from the integral of $\bar{M}$ and another term $xy$ resulting from the integral of $\bar{N}.$ Could anyone explain this to me, please?

Comment: You don't add the two results from integration. You are searching for a _single_ function $f$ such that $f_{x}=y+1-x^{-1}$ _and_ $f_{y}=x$. The first equation gives you $f=xy+1-\ln x$, the second $f=xy$ (ignoring constants). Clearly, $f$ must contain all the explicit terms that appear in both expressions after integration, which means it must have the terms $xy$ (which appears in both results), and $1$ and $-\ln x$ (which appears in only the first). Hence, _an_ $f$ that satisfies both ODEs is $f = xy+1-\ln x$. You can check that $f = \color{red}2xy+1-\ln x$ _does not_ satisfy the ODEs on $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the idea is to find $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\vec{\nabla} f \cdot (dx,dy) = f_x(x,y) dx + f_y(x,y)dy = (y+1-1/x)dx + xdy
$$
where $f_z(x,y)$ denotes the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to the variable $z$.

Let's solve the second side first. If $f_y(x,y) = x$ then
$$
f(x,y) = \int f_y(x,y)dy = \int xdy = x\int dy = xy + c(x).
$$
Note that $c(x)$ is the constant of integration, and therefore cannot depend on the variable of integration (which here is $y$).

Now that the general form of $f(x,y)$ is known, note that
$$
f_x(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[xy + c(x)\right] = y + c'(x).
$$
However, we know from the original problem that $f_x(x,y) = y+1-1/x$. Putting this together, we see that $c'(x) = 1 - 1/x$, and therefore,
$$
c(x) = \int \left( 1 - \frac1x\right)dx = x - \ln x + k,
$$
where $k$ now cannot depend on either $x$ or $y$. Thus,
$$
f(x,y) = xy + c(x) = xy + x - \ln x + k.
$$

Comment: I can not see any $f_{z}$ before the third line.

Comment: $f_z$ can be with respect to any variable, e.g. if you define $f_z$, you are defining both $f_x$ and $f_y$ at the same time (set $z=x$ or $z=y$ as needed). It's just a definition shorthand.

Comment: So the problem is that the solution did not show how to find the constant functions either in $x$ or in $y$?

Comment: @Smart20 there is really no problem. The author used a quick shorthand to combine both anti-derivatives, and you did not understand why it was obvious that they should be combined that way -- so I produced a more detailed explanation to help you follow the author's logic.

Answer (score 2):

You can aslos solve it this way:
$$(xy+x-1)dx+x^2dy=0$$
$$xydx+x^2dy+(x-1)dx=0$$
$$x(ydx+xdy)+(x-1)dx=0$$
$$x(dxy)+(x-1)dx=0$$
$$dxy+\dfrac {(x-1)}{x}dx=0$$
After integration it gives
$$xy+x-\ln |x|=C$$